# Permit argparse global flags after subcommand

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argparse to build a command with subcommands:

mycommand [GLOBAL FLAGS] subcommand [FLAGS]

I would like the global flags to work whether they are before or after the subcommand.  Is there a clean way to do this that doesn't involve repeating code?

For example:

```
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subparser_name')

  parser.add_argument('--disable')    # This flag...

  sp = subparsers.add_parser('compile')
  sp.add_argument('zones', nargs='*')
  sp.add_argument('--disable')        # Is repeated...

  sp = subparsers.add_parser('launch')
  sp.add_argument('zones', nargs='*')
  sp.add_argument('--disable')        # over and over...
```

I want to do this for many flags, so repeating myself over and over seems... unpythonic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [`parents`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#parents) argparse feature:

> Sometimes, several parsers share a common set of arguments. Rather
>   than repeating the definitions of these arguments, a single parser
>   with all the shared arguments and passed to parents= argument to
>   ArgumentParser can be used.

Define a base parent `ArgumentParser`, add arguments that will be shared across subparsers. Then, add subparsers and set your base parser as a parent by providing `parents` keyword argument:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subparser_name')

base_subparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
# define common shared arguments
base_subparser.add_argument('--disable')

sp = subparsers.add_parser('compile', parents=[base_subparser])
# define custom arguments
sp = subparsers.add_parser('launch', parents=[base_subparser])
# define custom arguments
```

Note that `add_help=False` here helps to avoid problems with [conflicting `help` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839957/argparseargumenterror-argument-h-help-conflicting-option-strings-h).

Also see: [Python argparse - Add argument to multiple subparsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498595/python-argparse-add-argument-to-multiple-subparsers).

Comment: "I would like the global flags to work *whether they are before or after the subcommand.*" I believe this solution does not work when the flags are provided before the subcommand on the command-line. I have tried *also* applying the base_subparser as a parent to the top-level parser, but this behaves badly for required=True arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues in your example:

1) The use of '--disable' in both the parser and subparsers.  [Nested ArgumentParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178097)
deals with that overlapping `dest`.

2) The repeated set of arguments in the subparsers.  `parents` is certainly one way to simplify that.  But you could easily write your own code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subparser_name')

parser.add_argument('--disable', dest='main_disable')    # This flag...

for name in ['compile', 'launch']:
    sp = subparsers.add_parser(name)
    sp.add_argument('zones', nargs='*')
    sp.add_argument('--disable', dest=name+'_disable')        # Is repeated...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for argparse solution, but as you also call for a Pythonic solution, I will deliberately propose an alternative using package `docopt`:

get it:

```
$ pip install docopt
```

Write your code into `mycommand` file:

```
"""
Usage:
    mycommand compile [--disable] <zone>...
    mycommand launch  [--disable] <zone>...

Arguments:
    <zone>  zone name

Options:
  -h --help
  --disable  disable

"""
from docopt import docopt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    print args
```

Then call it from command line:

basic help (no arguments):

```
$ python mycommand
Usage:
    mycommand compile [--disable] <zone>...
    mycommand launch  [--disable] <zone>...
```

Asking for a help:

```
$ python mycommand -h
Usage:
    mycommand compile [--disable] <zone>...
    mycommand launch  [--disable] <zone>...

Arguments:
    <zone>  zone name

Options:
  -h --help
  --disable  disable
```

Using compile subcommand:

```
$ python mycommand compile zoneAlfa zoneBeta
{'--disable': False,
 '<zone>': ['zoneAlfa', 'zoneBeta'],
 'compile': True,
 'launch': False}
```

add flag --disable:

```
$ python mycommand compile --disable zoneAlfa zoneBeta
{'--disable': True,
 '<zone>': ['zoneAlfa', 'zoneBeta'],
 'compile': True,
 'launch': False}
```

launch subcommand works too:

```
$ python mycommand launch --disable zoneAlfa zoneBeta
{'--disable': True,
 '<zone>': ['zoneAlfa', 'zoneBeta'],
 'compile': False,
 'launch': True}
```

My usage of argument parsers started with argparse too, and I hated the complexity of code, which was needed for doing something.

Later I turned into `plac`, which is very efficient way for turning a python function into very usable command for console.

Still, I was limited by set of rules to follow and understand, which were not very clear to me in many cases. With `docopt` I appreciate, that I can write the docstring first, following standard rules of POSIX, and then use it in my code. If you would care about validation of arguments, I will direct you to samples of this great package.